# How can I get reposted post info? Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm making a small social network on Django. I want to make repost feature.

I have `Post` model in `models.py`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField('Post text')
    image = models.ImageField('Image', upload_to='post_pics', blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Date')
    liked = models.ManyToManyField(User, default=None, blank=True, related_name='liked_by_user')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

Then I created the `Repost` model, that takes `Post` model:

```
class Repost(Post):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='reposted_post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Then I tried to create a repost with admin panel. New was post created, but how can I get info (user, text, image, date and likes) of post that I reposted and paste it in my repost?

Part of my `html`:

```
{% for p in post %}
    <p>{{ p.user.username }}</p>
    <p>{{ p.text }}</p>
    <p>{{ p.date }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say you have a queryset of `Repost` objects. You can then simply do

```
for repost in Repost.objects.all():
    # Print username and text of the original post.
    print(repost.post.user.username, repost.post.text)
```

If you have `Post` objects instead, you go via the `related_name`, like

```
for post in Post.objects.all():
    # Prints all reposts associated with the `post`
    print(post.reposted_post.all())
```